# In MVC4 application I need to bind the database table columns values as a Grid header. Is this possible in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4 application I can able to bind the database table columns into the Grid Header. But I need to bind the database table columns values as a Grid header. Is this possible in MVC?

Example:

tbl_staticfield table have the fieldname  Column this column have some values,that values need to bind the Grid header and then the corresponding field name have some values these values are stored  tbl_customfielddetails these also bind under the corresponding Grid header.

Comment: IF a table has more than one record then how many headers you'll have? Please elaborate your problem.

Comment: Yes I have 18 columns now as a header.But it is possible to increment in the future..

Comment: Ok, which grid control you're using for this now?

Comment: Problem is not related with MVC but the logics.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the webgrid object, first argument is source(rows), second is column names(List of columns). In your case, it would be dynamic. So it would be like

```
var Columns = context.tbl_staticfield.select(m => m.fieldname).toList();
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, Columns, ....);
```

I assume `context` is your database context.

**Ref:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx

```
public WebGrid(
    IEnumerable<Object> source,
    IEnumerable<string> columnNames,
    string defaultSort,
    int rowsPerPage,
    bool canPage,
    bool canSort,
    string ajaxUpdateContainerId,
    string ajaxUpdateCallback,
    string fieldNamePrefix,
    string pageFieldName,
    string selectionFieldName,
    string sortFieldName,
    string sortDirectionFieldName
)
```